# N^2 substring search using Pandas DataFrames

Tags: python, pandas

I have two pandas DataFrames containing strings and substrings:

```
import pandas as pd
strings = pd.DataFrame(
    [
        {"id": 0, "string": "abcdef"},
        {"id": 1, "string": "bcdef"},
        {"id": 2, "string": "cdef"}
    ]
)

substrings = pd.DataFrame(
    [
        {"id": 0, "string": "a"},
        {"id": 1, "string": "bc"},
        {"id": 2, "string": "def"}
    ]
)
```

I want to find the indices of all occurrences of each substring in each string. Right now, I'm doing something like

```
substrings.apply(
    lambda substring: strings["string"].findall(substring.string),
    axis=1
)
```

Is there a better/more efficient way to do this?

Comment: What is expected output?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need:

```
s = strings["string"].str.findall('|'.join(substrings.string))
print (s)
0    [a, bc, def]
1       [bc, def]
2           [def]
Name: string, dtype: object
```

Comment: I believe this is still `O(n^2)`.

Comment: @gmds - hmmm, is there solution with no `O(n^2)` ?

Comment: Probably there is some complex algorithm that can do it in less, but that would be outside the scope of `pandas`. This is cleaner than OP's code, but I don't think it answers the question "is there a more efficient way to do this".